# Android Studio não exibe caracteres em português corretamente

Tags: java, android, android-studio, codificação-de-caracteres, configuração

O meu projeto não está exibindo nenhum caracter em português corretamente. Quando eu exibo uma string como "não", ele exibe "nÃ£o".

O estranho é que, quando eu chamo a string direto do `res/string.xml`, ele funciona corretamente. Alguém tem alguma ideia do por quê? Eu já perguntei no StackOverflow gringo e ninguém conseguiu me responder.

O que eu já tentei até agora:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Encondings, coloquei tudo UTF-8 e até alguns outros, dei rebuild/clean no projeto e nada, ainda tá igual.

Se for necessário, posso gravar um vídeo e upar no YouTube para mostrar!

EDIT:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso daí parece que é o que acontece quando você lê vários bytes e converte cada byte individualmente para caractere, ignorando o fato de que alguns caracteres precisam de mais de um byte para serem codificados. Você pode dizer mais a fundo qual é o procedimento que gera estas strings e o que ele faz? Se possível postar o código dele.

Comment: Olá! obrigado pela resposta. Postei uma imagem como exemplo!

Comment: Ele acontece **sempre** que eu vou exibir qualquer tipo de texto na tela, exceto pelo /res/strings.xml

Comment: Caro amigo, uma pergunte... Está usando Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Isso daí parece que é o que acontece quando você lê vários bytes e converte cada byte individualmente para caractere, ignorando o fato de que alguns caracteres precisam de mais de um byte para serem codificados.

Uma vez que mesmo as strings nos seus código-fontes estão sendo corrompidas e o código-fonte está em UTF-8, tente passar `-encoding UTF-8` como parâmetros de linha de comando para o compilador java. Por exemplo:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 SuaClasse.java
```

Comment: Olá amigo, obrigado pela resposta! Eu estou recebendo o seguinte erro quando aplico o código no terminal do android studio:

_'-encoding' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes._ estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: @DiegoFortes Sim, ele é um parâmetro de linha de comando do `javac`, e não o próprio comando. Atualizei a resposta, embora o meu exemplo deve ser simplista demais.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas sou bem leigo quando se trata de linhas de comando. Eu deveria usar o CMD do windows ou da própria IDE?

Comment: Você pode procurar na sua IDE para colocar isto como parâmetro para o compilador.

Comment: ainda com o mesmo problema :\

Comment: @DiegoFortes Então, eu não sei. :\